# how to normalize seaborn distplot, so that the bars add up to 1

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Seaborn [distplot](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) has a flag `norm_hist`. When switched on, the distplot is normalized so that it integrates to 1.

Here is a small example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randn(10000)
a = a[(-2<a) * (a<2)]

sns.distplot(a=a, bins=np.linspace(-2, 2, 6), norm_hist=True, kde=False)
plt.show()
```

This creates the following plot:

[image: distplot]

It looks a bit like a triangle and you can see that it integrates to 1. A triangle of width 4 and height 0.5 has the area 1.

Is it possible to normalize this while ignoring the width of each bin? So that the bars add up to 1 (it would have this behaviour if all bins together spanned a width of 1).

In my scenario, users are binned based on a continuous feature. In the distplot, I would like to show what percentage of users falls into each bin. But when the feature is rescaled, the heights of the corresponding bars change.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866520/plotting-histograms-whose-bar-heights-sum-to-1-in-matplotlib

Comment: thanks, I didn't see that. But the accepted answer only reproduces the problem. And the answer that should be accepted describes a solution for pyplot. It is based on a weights parameter, which is not exposed by seaborn.

Comment: Seaborn has a *hist_kw* parameter. But it's not clear why you would need to use seaborn anyways.

Comment: I suspect a XY problem here. What is the statistical function you want to plot ? CDF ? PDF ? Why do you want it to plot in y in [0;1] ? Makes me think of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55128462/how-to-normalize-seaborn-distplot/55131267#55131267